# Magento 2: Update Product Data Outside Magento with Tier Pricing

Tags: magento2, product, catalog

I have below script for Update Product records with Tier Pricing.

I have already Product SKU in CSV. On basis of that fetching Product Id & Try to update Record.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'magento2');

if (!$mysqli) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

$file_name = "final_sheet.csv";

// MAGENTO START
include('app/bootstrap.php');

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

if (($handle = fopen($file_name, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $i = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $i++;

        if ($i > 1) {

            $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
            $_productTierPrice = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductTierPriceManagementInterface');

            $productSKU = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($data[0]));
            $productDesc = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($data[1]));
            $productTierPrice = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($data[2]));
            $productTierPrice = (!empty($productTierPrice)) ? number_format($productTierPrice, 4) : '';

            $sql = "SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE  sku = '" . $productSKU . "';";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                    $entityId = $row['entity_id'];
                }

                echo "Product Id. " . $entityId . "<br />";

                $_product->load($entityId);
                $_product->setDescription($productDesc);

                $_product->save();

                $getData = $_product->getData();
                $_product->setData($getData);
                $_product->save();

                $sku = $productSKU; //Product sku
                $customerGroupId = 2; //Wholsaler group id
                $price = $productTierPrice;
                $qty = 1;

                $_productTierPrice->add($sku, $customerGroupId, $price, $qty);

                $_productTierPrice->save();
            } else {
                echo "Product Not Found";
                exit;
            }

            if ($i > 3)
                break;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

echo '<strong>Done</strong>';
```

**It's saving product description data in Database, but not showing in Admin.**

Comment: are you using 2 different data base in this script ?

Comment: Nope only one database. I have update on this data is stored for Description in Database & Table, but not displaying in Admin. I have cleared cache & all things. Still Issue

Comment: Is that data updated in database tables ?

Comment: Hi @AshishJagnani Check for http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143939/magento-2-data-stored-in-database-but-not-displaying-in-admin-frontend only for Short Description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// MAGENTO START
include('app/bootstrap.php');

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$file_name = "final_sheet.csv";

if (($handle = fopen($file_name, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $i = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $i++;

    if ($i > 1) {

        $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $_productTierPrice = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductTierPriceManagementInterface');

        $productSKU = trim($data[0]);
        $productDesc = trim($data[1]);
        $productTierPrice = trim($data[2]);
        $productTierPrice = (!empty($productTierPrice)) ? number_format($productTierPrice, 4) : '';

        $entityId = $_product->getIdBySku($productSKU);

        if ($entityId) {


            echo "Product Id. " . $entityId . "<br />";

            $_product->load($entityId);
            $_product->setStoreId(0);
            $_product->setDescription($productDesc);

            $_product->save();

            $sku = $productSKU; //Product sku
            $customerGroupId = 2; //Wholsaler group id
            $price = $productTierPrice;
            $qty = 1;

            $_productTierPrice->add($sku, $customerGroupId, $price, $qty);

        } else {
            echo "Product Not Found";
            exit;
        }

        if ($i > 3)
            break;
    }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}


echo '<strong>Done</strong>';
```

Comment: It's storing data in DB. So above is not the cause i think

Comment: Try my updated answer and check.

Comment: Nope i tried, but still description is not showing :(

Comment: Try with set admin store id in product like : $_product->setStoreId(0);

Comment: Hi @Ashish. Thanks a lot it's working fine. Please remove `$_productTierPrice->save();` Not Needed & need to add  `$_product->setStoreId(0);`